# Python Dataframe Binary Encoding

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, analytics, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| User | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | b |

I want 1 row per user with the products as columns where it gives a 1 or 0 if the user purchased the product or not, how can I do this?

Comment: Checkout #Q9 from the dupe linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.pivot_table(index="User", columns="Product", aggfunc=len).fillna(0)

# Result:

Product    a    b    c
User                  
1        1.0  1.0  0.0
2        1.0  0.0  1.0
3        0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is "[**cross tabulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)" or simply **crosstab**. Pandas has [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for the same.

```
pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Product'])

Product  a  b  c
User            
1        1  1  0
2        1  0  1
3        0  1  0
```